# How to display both the formula and the result of the formula in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to have a cell in Google Sheets to display the entire summation for example:

```
5+5 = 10
```

If I do the following:

```
=5+5
```

The cell will only show `10` it doesn't show the `5+5`.

Another way I have tried is:

```
="5+5 = " &5+5
```

While this works, if I need to modify the formula I have to change the formula in the quotes and after the & sign.

Is there a way to simplify this so that if I need to change the formula, I only have to touch the formula once in the cell?

Comment: No there isn't, unless you are okay with building a custom function using google app scripts or excel vba user defined function.  Seems easest to just put `="5+5=25"`

Answer (score 1):

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

You can do this via `FORMULATEXT`

In A1,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1),".*?&",)&"="&(5+5)
```

It will display:

```
(5+5)=10
```

You only need to modify the math and details are retrieved through `FORMULATEXT` and `REGEX` is used to remove `FORMULATEXT` itself. Furthermore, there won't be circular reference as the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792) say,

> If the cell passed into FORMULATEXT references the cell that contains the FORMULATEXT formula, then FORMULATEXT will properly handle this and avoid a circular reference.

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

You just need to use `RIGHT` and `FIND` instead of `REGEXREPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1)&"="&A1, "=";;1)
```

[image]

arrayformula would be:

```
=IFNA(BYROW(A1:A10; LAMBDA(xx; SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(xx)&"="&xx; "=";;1))))
```

[image]